# How to get Grunt to run tasks based on Visual Studio build mode?

Tags: build, gruntjs, visual-studio-2015, task-runner-explorer

I have Grunt with tasks up  and running fine but now it runs all tasks regardless of build mode (Debug /Release).

So my question is how can i detect build mode and run different tasks depending on the current mode?

So what i want to achieve is something like :
if (buildmode=='Debug'){just combine js files} else {also do tasks X, Y, Z, }

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible at the moment, I suggest you instead control which files get loaded from the view depending on the new ASPNET_ENV environment variable.

Comment: The workaround for me was to create separate bundles and depending on config i include the desired bundle in C# code 
  
#if DEBUG
include the appropriate files resulting from tasks 
#endif

Maybe not the best way but for now it floats the boat ... but if someone else has any bright ideas they are more then welcome to share 8-)